# Get parameter and attributes of a class in .cc file

Tags: networking, simulation, omnet++

The problem is: Several mobile elements(ME) are employed to gather sensory data from the field. first the nodes should be clusterd and some energy-riched CHs should be selected as rendezvous nodes(RN).sensor nodes deliver their data to RNs and finally the mobile elements should visit these RNs to gather data.
The main part of this work is Estimation of routing paths toward RNs.
1) how can I do clustering and determining the RNs?
2)how can I force mobile elements to pass my defined movement paths?
I used INET wireless showcases to simulate this problem.
first part: I don't know. Plz help!
as the second part of my problem( movement of ME) I did:

```
module MEpath extends AdhocHost
{
    parameters:
    @display("i=device/cellphone");
    @class(MEpath);
    mobilityType = "MassMobility";
}
network MyNet
{
parameters:
    int numHost;
    int numME;
    string mediumType = default("IdealRadioMedium");

submodules:
    visualizer: IntegratedCanvasVisualizer {
        parameters:
            @display("p=47,16");
    }
    configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
        parameters:
            @display("p=47,97");
    }
    radioMedium:  <mediumType> like IRadioMedium {
        parameters:
            @display("p=55,271");
    }
    lifecycleController: LifecycleController {
        parameters:
            @display("p=34,176");
    }
    host[numHost]: AdhocHost {
        parameters:
            @display("p=222,300");
    }
    mobileHost[numME]: MEpath {
        @display("p=296,207;i=device/pocketpc");
    }
}
```

Is defining MEpath module correct or not? which class or .cc file should I change? what should I write in MEpath.cc?

> maybe it is unusual but at all I have problem in working with omnet++ and inet manual. I couldn't find out which attribute and parameter of a class should I change? !

Comment: Could you provide more information about your problem: do you use an example of INET or own project, which type of node do you use, how the node's position should be changed etc.

Comment: According first question: `INET` doesn't contain any clustering mechanism. And this question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). According second question: how do you want to introduce a path that ME should go through - as set of points, or the rules of movement, or other way?

Comment: @JerzyD. thanks for your answer. MEs should follow a heuristic algorithm but for simplicity,now I want to change them as a set of point .

Comment: @JerzyD. thank you very much. and if I want to implement a heuristic tour planning , what should I do? How can I call and parametrize mobile elements in .cc file?

Comment: The best way is to prepare own mobility type. To do that you should define a new NED file which inherits from `MovingMobilityBase`. In the NED file you may add the parameters you need. Then you should prepare a C++ class (in *.h and *.cc) which inherits from `inet::MovingMobilityBase`. The API contains methods you have to overwrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ad. 2.** You can use `BonnMotionMobility`. It is explained in [INET Framework 4.0 User's Guide](https://inet.omnetpp.org/users-guide/chap22.html#sec:mobility:replaying-trace-files) as well as in [INET API Reference](https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/neddoc/index.html?p=inet.mobility.single.BonnMotionMobility.html). It required a file which contains several values: time, x, and y, separated by a space. An example of this file you can find in `examples` directory of `INET` for example: `examples\mobility\bonnmotion_small.movements`.
To use this type of mobility you should set in `omnetpp.ini` something like:

```
**.mobileHost*.mobility.typename = "BonnMotionMobility"
**.mobileHost*.mobility.traceFile = "your_trace_file"
```

Moreover, you should remove this line:

```
mobilityType = "MassMobility";
```

from your `MEpath` definition (because this way it is [hardcoded](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:config-sim:parameter-settings), and it cannot be controlled via `omnetpp.ini`).
The definition of `MEpath` is correct. It requires a `*.h` and `*.cc` files that contain a [declaration and definition](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:defining-simple-modules) of `MEpath` C++ class.